# handle multi denominational array to array index as array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have multidimensional   array in php this is array format I need to handle this data in loop and want each array value single time with its index.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => third.png
            [1] => second.png
            [2] => first.png
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/png
            [1] => image/png
            [2] => image/png
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpOPmQcB
            [1] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpk0j1yp
            [2] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpS2mhVd
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 179440
            [1] => 102238
            [2] => 75915
        )

)
```

I want to handle multidimensional array with new  index for example this multidimensional array in core php please help me out

```
array(
    Array
   (
    [name] => third.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpOPmQcB
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 179440
   )
    Array
  (
    [name] => second.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] =>/opt/lampp/temp/phpk0j1yp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 102238
  )
    Array
  (
    [name] => first.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpS2mhVd
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 75915
  )
)
```

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything, since both images are empty. Other than that, before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made some attempts yourself. If you then get stuck on something _specific_, you can come back, show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. We're glad to help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: can i edit this question?

Comment: Sure. Just click "edit".

Comment: done now is better clear to images

Comment: Better. We're still missing your attempt, though (as I mentioned in my first comment). SO isn't a free coding service where you just post your requirements and we'll code it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the keys of the array with array_keys.
Then you need to loop the count of one of the subarrays. I get the count from the first subarray using the `$keys` variable.

I nest a for and a foreach to build the array you expect.
This method is dynamic and will work with a larger input array both on number of subarrays and number of items.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$count = count($arr[$keys[0]]);

for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
    foreach($keys as $val){
        $new[$i][$val] = $arr[$val][$i];
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
            ["name"] => "third.png"
            ["type"] => "image/png"
            ["tmp_name"] => "/opt/lampp/temp/phpOPmQcB"
            ["error"] => 0 
            ["size"] => 179440
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
            ["name"] => "second.png"
            ["type"] => "image/png"
            ["tmp_name"] => "/opt/lampp/temp/phpk0j1yp"
            ["error"] => 0
            ["size"] => 102238
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
            ["name"] => "first.png"
            ["type"] => "image/png"
            ["tmp_name"] => "/opt/lampp/temp/phpS2mhVd"
            ["error"] => 0
            ["size"] => 75915
      }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/4g40N